# Random keyboard actions after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04

Tags: gnome, upgrade, keyboard, 22.04

Lately (almost five days ago), I upgraded my desktop from Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04. As soon as I started using the new version of Ubuntu, I noticed that from time to time (i.e., during heavy keyboard use, a few times in an hour):

- the cursor moves to other random locations in the document (as if the arrow or <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd> keys were pressed);
- new tabs are opened randomly in browser (as if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> was pressed);
- switches to other application windows (as if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, or something similar was pressed);
- cursor skips to other cells in a *Calc* sheet (and sometimes deletes or updates other cells);
- even the GNOME terminal screen was maximized once.

This is rather annoying, since I haven't experienced such a thing during my 3+ years of Ubuntu usage on that same hardware (a decent notebook with 6 core i7-8750H, 24GB RAM, SSD for boot and home filesystem) and all recent Ubuntu versions (18.10, 19.04, 19.10, 20.04, 20.10, 21.04, and 21.10).

I am using standard GNOME version (no Wayland) with, NVIDIA (version 510) proprietary driver.

USB mouse and touchpad seem to work OK.

**Q:** Is there anybody else experiencing similar problems in Ubuntu 22.04? How can I narrow down the cause of the problem?

Please note that, this annoying behavior occurs completely random and I cannot reproduce the problem whenever I want to.

---

**4 May 2022 Update:**

I tested with **Live USB Ubuntu 22.04** session for more than one hour. This strange behavior does not seem to occur there during the short test I made. Note however that the Live session does not use NVIDIA graphics, but the internal graphics card with the "*NV137 / Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)*" driver.

---

**4 June 2022 Update:**

- Under **Settings** → **Accessibility** nothing non-standard is selected.
- `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and re-installation of `xserver-xorg-input-all` do not seem to help.
- ⚠️ However, **it seems that my notebook's touchpad is "hyper" sensitive and it registers click commands just when my hands and fingers are over the keyboard, but at least 1 cm away from the touchpad. In my opinion this is the cause and I am testing this right now.**

***Problem:***

I remember, in previous versions of Ubuntu, I was disabling the touchpad, because I was not using it normally (except in very rare cases when my USB mouse was having a problem).

*Now, in version 42 of GNOME, the options under **Settings** → **Mouse & Keyboard** → **Touchpad** have no effect and I have to disable the touchpad from command line.*

The command `synclient Touchpadoff=1` disables the touchpad with one exception: Even though the touchpad stops moving the pointer and taps also are disabled, the touchpad still responds to physical clicks on it.

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ A4Tech USB Mouse                          id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ UNIW0001:00 093A:0003 Mouse               id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ UNIW0001:00 093A:0003 Touchpad            id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ HD Webcam: HD Webcam                      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

After looking at the above output, I tried and found out that `xinput --disable 14` is also needed to disable the touchpad completely.

So, the question that remains is this:

*Why the GNOME options under **Settings** → **Mouse & Keyboard** → **Touchpad** do not work?*

***Note:*** It seems that this problem is present in X11, but not in Wayland. However, I have to use X11, because Wayland has many other problems. As another note: I just tested with a "Live ISO" session, and although it runs under X11 too, it does not exhibit this problem.

Comment: do you experience the same issues if you use a live USB session to run Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Comment: @24601 I just tested with live USB for almost an hour with no such problem.

Comment: Well, that is good news then. Maybe something important has been eliminated from your investigations in that case. Perhaps now consider a vanilla install from scratch? Back up everything important first 

Comment: Reinstalling or just creating a new user is always an option. But, surely there should be some simpler solution, like modifying or resetting/deleting a corrupt (config) file.

Comment: depends on your experience level and the time you can allocate to it. In most cases a vanilla re-installation is the best solution since you start at a clean base, as it were.

Comment: "Why the GNOME options under Settings → Mouse & Keyboard → Touchpad do not work?" ... I guess it's an issue with your specific [touchpad model](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=ps/2:1336-1336-uniw0001-00-093a-touchpad) .. It seems not fully supported by many Linux distributions ... [Debugging Touchpad Detection](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection) might help.

Comment: @Raffa My problem is exactly the same as the one mentioned in https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408042/touchpad-cant-be-disabled-in-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: Please don't put the answer inside the question! Use the **Answer Your Own Question** button below. Then accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that my notebook's touchpad is "hyper" sensitive and it registers tap-to-click commands just when my hands and fingers are over the keyboard, but at least 1 cm away from the touchpad!

I remember, in previous versions of Ubuntu, I was disabling the touchpad, because I was not using it normally; except in very rare cases when my USB mouse was having a problem.

However, it seemed that recently (?) the options under GNOME **Settings** → **Mouse & Keyboard** → **Touchpad** started having no effect: *The touchpad continued working even when it seemed "disabled".*

Initially, I had to use the command `xinput --disable 14` to disable it.

But, later I realized that the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package has some [problems with disabling touchpad](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=xserver-xorg-input-synaptics). So, I just removed it and the ability to change touchpad settings using GNOME **Settings** → **Mouse & Touchpad** → **Touchpad** was restored:

```
sudo apt remove xserver-xorg-input-synaptics
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try the following solutions **one at a time** in their order below and check if the issue is resolved before trying the next solution.

#### First Solution:

Check under **Settings -> Accessibility** and make sure nothing unwanted is enabled. Namely the **Typing** and **Pointing & Clicking** sections.

#### Second Solution:

- Reconfigure your keyboard by running the following command in the terminal and following the instructions:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
  ```
- Then reboot your system.

#### Third Solution:

- Install(update) input drivers(support) under **Xorg** like so:

  ```
  sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-all
  ```

  Or under **Wayland** like so:

  ```
  sudo apt install --reinstall libinput10
  ```
- Then reconfigure your keyboard by running the following command in the terminal and following the instructions:

  ```
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
  ```
- Then reboot your system.

#### Fourth Solution:

If you reached here then the issue is most likely not a keyboard configuration problem ... It's time to consider one of the following two things:

1. Your keyboard is **physically broken or faulty** and needs replacement.
2. It might **not be your keyboard** that is causing this behavior but rather something else which could be either hardware/software related *(like a faulty/unsupported touchpad, mouse or external additional keyboard)* and the following debugging resources are recommended:

   - [Debugging Touchpad Detection](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingTouchpadDetection).
   - [Debugging Mouse Detection](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingMouseDetection).
   - [Debugging Keyboard Detection](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKeyboardDetection).
   - [Hardware for Linux](https://linux-hardware.org/).

Comment: Thanks again for your effort. Asking a question in AU has two main purposes. (1) To solve that very problem of the OP. (2) To help solve _similar_ problems of other users in the future. :D