# Touchpad doesn't work properly Dell Inspiron-3542

Tags: 18.04, 20.04, dell, touchpad, synaptics

Good evening Community,

It has been two years when my laptop suddenly stopped working, and it was not possible to turn it on. Many circuits on the motherboard burned out, and due to the Pandemic, we couldn't get a new suitable motherboard (Yes in some countries, even spare parts were impossible to get during Covid). Anyway, a couple of weeks ago, we finally found a new motherboard for my laptop, and I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04.

I noticed that the touchpad was acting weirdly. The pointer had some erratic movements and there were clicking and menu-tabs everywhere. At some point, the touchpad stopped working and was not responsive, but the system was able to detect it. The most annoying part, was that when the touchpad was not responding, it was impossible to suspend the system. Furthermore, when the touchpad stops working on Ubuntu, it also stops on the Windows 7 partition.

Since the old installation Key for Windows was not valid anymore, I decided to remove all the old partitions and re-installed again a new system with Ubuntu 20.04. I tried many configurations and installed two different drivers, but the problem remained the same. I decided to get back to Ubuntu 18.04. Now installed, the pointer is more stable. It does not stop from working, but it moves erratically sometimes. I sent the laptop to get it checked again, but no hardware problems were detected.

Now I'm out of ideas, I would be grateful for any proposition. Thank you very much

**Update (Edit July 1st, 2022)**

I'm afraid that the same scenario with Ubuntu 20 is now occurring with Ubuntu 18. As a matter of fact, the touchpad stops from working after spending a lot of time working on the laptop. Again, and just like in Ubuntu 20, the system is not able to suspend and fails to suspend the Touchpad drivers.

This means that the issue has nothing to do with the OS, and it's a hardware problem. I'm wondering if there is any possibility to remove the touchpad from the *Wakeup* list. I will then definitely disable the touchpad and use the mouse instead.

**Update (Edit July 16th, 2022)**

As I said in the last update, it's a hardware issue. The only solution I found is to permanently disable the touchpad and use the mouse instead. In this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416810/how-to-remove-the-touchpad-from-the-wakeup-list-ubuntu-18-04), I'm giving a step-by-step configuration to manually disable the touchpad, to make sure that the system will not detect it. This way, the system will not have to suspend it while hibernating.

-Meriem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Random keyboard actions after upgrade from 21.10 to 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1406509/random-keyboard-actions-after-upgrade-from-21-10-to-22-04)

Comment: No unfortunately. This post suggests to disable the touchpad, which did not resolve my problem. I shall give an update about the issue, since I got an other problem now. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: It does sound like a hardware problem - you had the same issue when on windows 7? - in that case it can’t be the Ubuntu os that’s causing the problem. The fact that it’s glitchy on 18 and 20.04 and windows 7 (with a history of being in a laptop suffering a major hardware (mobo) failure) - I’d say this is almost certainly a problem with the touchpad itself. I’d probably just accept having to use a mouse, but if you can get hold of one and have the time, replace the touchpad.

Comment: Not quite the same problem. I didn't notice, for instance, any weird movement on Windows 7. The touchpad only stops from working and is can not be detected from the configuration panel. But I think you're right. It looks like a hardware issue. Now I'm facing the problem of Ubuntu not able to suspend!