# How to remove the touchpad from the "wakeup" list Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, suspend, dell, touchpad

Good evening Community,
I'm facing an issue with my laptop's touchpad (Dell Inspiron-3542). It stops working from time to time and doesn't respond to any movement (I've given all the details in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416320/touchpad-doesnt-work-properly-dell-inspiron-3542) of mine). The problem is when the touchpad's stopped from working, it still can be detected by the system, but when I try to suspend the laptop, the system got awakened after three attempts of suspension.
It's absolutely impossible to suspend the system when the touchpad is not working. This is what I get after checking in the logs:

```
    Kernel: i2c_hid_acpi i2c-DLL0651:00: PM: failed to suspend async: error -110
    Kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
```

I'm wondering if there is any possibility to remove the touchapd from the wakeup list, so the system will not have to suspend it after I close the lid?

Thank you in advance!

-Meriem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was not to remove the touchpad from the "*wakeup*" list after all. All I had to do is to manually disable the touchpad from the configuration file.
The system use by default **libinput** driver to handle touchpad, keyboard, webcam and other input devices. I hade to go to libinput configuration file, in my case was */usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf* and comment the lines related to the touchpad, as follows:

```
#Section "InputClass"
#        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
#        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
#        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
#        Driver "libinput"
#EndSection
```

After rebooting the system, and typing *xinput list* I could see that the touchpad was no longer detected. This way the system is now able to suspend without any problem.