# Ubuntu 22.04 not disabling trackpad

Tags: 22.04, mouse, dell, touchpad, xps

I disabled the touchpad on my Dell XPS 13 to work around a bug (the mouse cursor jumps around randomly as I type, selects text,  etc.), possibly in 22.04, but the OS ignores it and the touchpad remains active.[image]

Why, you may ask, do I think disabling the touchpad would help? Because I noticed that as long as my hands are far enough away from the touchpad, the problem doesn't occur. So before I open up the laptop and pull the plug on the touchpad, I thought I'd check in here. Has anyone else experienced this in 22.04?

Comment: See also this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1412253/855322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Find the xinput ID for the touchpad

open a terminal and use the command:

```
xinput list
```

This will output something like this:

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA30D2:00 06CB:CE08                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA30D2:00 06CB:CE08                     id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ SYNA30D2:00 06CB:CE08                     id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
```

For the next part, try all the ID numbers for the slave pointer to find out which is your touchpad. Mine works with `id=12`.

## Test

Enter the command:

```
xinput set-prop N 'Device Enabled' 0    # Disable touchpad
```

Replace `N` with the number in id=. before entering the above command and then try the touchpad to see if it is disabled. If it does not work, use the command:

```
xinput set-prop N 'Device Enabled' 1    # Enable touchpad
```

This command will enable the device disabled by the previous command. Note which `N`  disables the touchpad.

## Script

Save the script below as `/home/$USER/bin/touchtoggle`.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Purpose: Toggles the touchpad on and off with keyboard shortcut Ctrl+Z
# set via System settings > Keyboard > keyboard Shortcuts > Custom

# Change the ID below to your touchpad ID

ID=12

TOGGLE=$HOME/.touchpadtoggle

if [ ! -e $TOGGLE ]; then
    touch $TOGGLE
    xinput set-prop $ID 'Device Enabled' 0    # Disable touchpad
else
    rm $TOGGLE
    xinput set-prop $ID 'Device Enabled' 1    # Enable touchpad
fi
exit 0
```

Use your file manager to set the script executable, or use the terminal and enter:

```
chmod +x /home/$USER/bin/touchtoggle
```

Check if the script works as expected by running it from the terminal by typing:

```
touchtoggle
```

## Shortcut

If it works assign a keyboard shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, or something similar in **System settings > Keyboard > keyboard Shortcuts: View and Customize Shortcuts > Custom Shortcuts**. Enter the following:

- Name: Toggle touchpad on and off
- Command: /home/$USER/bin/touchtoggle
- Shotcut: Press the shortcut you want

Change `$USER` to your username.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; you made my day! In fact, it was device ID, the Touchpad pointer, that needed disabling: ruomini@ruomini-XPS-13-9370:~$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ DELL07E6:00 06CB:76AF Touchpad           id=14 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                       id=19 [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Bluetooth Mouse M336/M337/M535 Mouse     id=22 [slave  pointer  (2)]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fully disabling the touchpad, disabling only "Tap to click" will be of equal help to you. The setting is in "Settings", "Mouse & Touchpad". The touchpad remains functional, clicking however now must be done by pressing the touchpad mechanically down.

Personally, I can quickly toggle the setting on or off by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. This is effectuated by a small script triggered by that shortcut key. Here is how in case you are interested:

**1. Create the script**

Using a text editor, copy following script into a file `~/.local/bin/toggletouchpad`. If the directory `~/.local/bin` does not yet exist, create it then log out and back in so it gets included in your search `PATH`.

```
#!/bin/bash
STATUS=$(gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click)
case $STATUS in
    true )
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false
    ;;
    false )
        gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click true
    ;;
esac
```

**2. Make the script executable**

Use your file manager to set the script executable, or use the terminal: `chmod +x ~/.local/bin/toggletouchpad`

**3. Assign it to a shortcut key**

Add a shortcut key in "Settings" - "Keyboard", "Keyboard Shortcuts". As "command", fill in `toggletouchpad`.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't help. I think the problem is that there's a capacitive coupling between my hands and the touchpad, so even if  OS obeyed the Disable Tap to click (which it doesn't in my case), it wouldn't help.

Comment: So disabling tap to click in the Settings also has no effect for you?

Comment: This is a more elegant solution than my answer. It works for me. I can move the cursor all the time. The keyboard shortcut toggles tap-to-click on and off.

Comment: @user68186 more elegant and easier. However, both your approach (turning touchpad of as OP wanted) and my approach (disable Tap to click) may not work for OP, considering his comment.